# Gradle should not wait for debugger to attach

Tags: java, debugging, gradle

does anybody know a way to let gradle run the application in debug mode but not wait until the debugger attachs? I know this is a nice feature to have the debugger attached when the application starts. My google research was not fruitful.

The command I execute to start the application in debug mode.

```
./gradlew appRunDebug
```

(which is equivalent to `./gradlew appRun --debug-jvm`)

What I see then on the console after several seconds:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
<============-> 97% EXECUTING [1m 2s]
```

At this point I have to attach my debugger to the process in order that the start routine continues. But I just want to have the debug port open and the application fully running without attaching my debugger.

How can this be achived? Thanks for any help. Even the confirmation that this is not possible.

Comment: How did you enabled debugging? Usually there is a flag you can set.

Comment: My command above is a shortcut for `./gradlew appRun --debug-jvm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Debugger-support.html, from Gradle 1.1.8 onwards, you should be able to set the `debugSuspend` property to `false` and `appRunDebug` won't start the application in suspended mode.